# Embed Python's grpcio module into a Bazel project

Tags: python, grpc, bazel

I tried several different ways to embed the Python `grpcio` module into my Bazel project but unfortunately, none of them works correctly.

As far as I know, Bazel does not support injection of plugins into the Python environment (so you can directly run `import grpcio`). Note that Bazel does not support virtual-env and other tools (buildout...).

I found a way to include Pypi packages thanks to [this proof of concept](https://github.com/gengo/rules_pypi) but unfortunately it does not work for grpc.io (environment variables are missing).

I am trying to debug the plugin, but I wonder if there is a better way to include `grpcio` module since the code is based on Bazel?

Comment: Can't install via `pip install grpcio` so that's "globally" available as suggested here https://github.com/pubref/rules_protobuf/issues/29 ? Is not a viable option in your case? Plus you should `imoprt grpc` and not `import grpcio` ...right? But I'm pretty sure you have done that already...

Comment: Yup. Some context: I am working on a project involving several technologies/languages. We use Bazel as our test/build/run tool. Since Bazel supports Python, I would like to make a Python module fully based on Bazel. I achieved to support some Pypi module but not grpcio, due to compilation the compilation and its library requirements...

Comment: [We intend to start work on officially building gRPC Python with Bazel very soon but don't yet have a good estimate on how long it will take](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8079).

Answer (score 1):

As Nathaniel mentioned in the comments, bazel support for gRPC Python is still work in progress.

However, pubref https://github.com/pubref/rules_protobuf offers rules for bazel that support gRPC for all languages (including Python). I have used them for Java and they worked very well.

There is also a gRPC blog post about those rules: http://www.grpc.io/blog/bazel_rules_protobuf